# cookies set by javascript not retrievable

Tags: javascript, cookies, codeigniter-3

I have this script in JS

```
function setCookie(name, value, days) {
  var d = new Date;
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + 24*60*60*1000*days);
  document.cookie = name + "=" + value + ";path=/;expires=" + d.toGMTString();
}
```

I can see in my Chrome browser options->settings that the cookie name "workLocation" is set. The domain for the cookie is "/", 'send for' option is "Any kind of Connection" and 'accessible to script' option is "Yes".

when I call the cookie using JS code below, it returns null.

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var v = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + name + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
    return v ? v[2] : null;
}
alert(getCookie("workLocation"));
```

I had tried using PHP to show cookies var_dump($_COOKIE); but it only shows codeigniter cookies "ci_session" and "httpUser". I had used the same javascript to set and get cookies and it's working, except for this page. Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cookie in server and in client is different the cookie in server is stored in

> Local Storage

and the cookie in client is stored in

> Cookies

if you want to get the cookie from js u can use this functions :

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var user = getCookie("username");
    if (user != "") {
        alert("Welcome again " + user);
    } else {
        user = prompt("Please enter your name:", "");
        if (user != "" && user != null) {
            setCookie("username", user, 365);
        }
    }
}
```

but if you want to get the cookie from php especially those session in CI

u can use this command `$this->session->userdata("key");`